# Laravel Livewire inline component return syntax error

Tags: laravel, heredoc, laravel-livewire

I am using Laravel 7

When I create an inline component by using this command,

```
php artisan livewire:make HelloWorld3 --inline
```

It returns me a syntax error

> ErrorException syntax error, unexpected end of file, expecting
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or heredoc end (T_END_HEREDOC) or ${
>   (T_DOLLAR_OPEN_CURLY_BRACES) or {$ (T_CURLY_OPEN) (View:
>   /var/www/html/l7livewire/resources/views/welcome.blade.php)

my HelloWorld3.php code at ap/http/livewire/

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class HelloWorld3 extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return <<<'blade'
            <div>
                {{-- Be like water. --}}
            </div>
        blade;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're running on PHP 7.2 - whereas this syntax expects you to be running on PHP 7.3.

PHP 7.3 introduced [flexible heredoc syntax](https://laravel-news.com/flexible-heredoc-and-nowdoc-coming-to-php-7-3) where it's possible to indent the ending delimiter of the heredoc string ( the "`blade;`") - prior to that, the ending delimiter could not be indented at all.

Your corrected code block to work on PHP 7.2 would be as follows:

```php
class HelloWorld3 extends Component
{
    public function render()
    {
        return <<<'blade'
            <div>
                {{-- Be like water. --}}
            </div>
blade;
    }
}
```